# Why is this code not returning the indices of the element in my 3D array?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d array called `V_exact` and within it there is a particular value I want to find which is given by `Potential(0.001,-0.0008,0.0035)`, where `Potential` is some function which takes in 3 coordinates and turns a value. 
Here  is the code I have tried to use:

```
%create axis vectors
x=-4*10^-3:0.1*10^-3:4*10^-3;
y=-4*10^-3:0.1*10^-3:4*10^-3;
z=-4*10^-3:0.1*10^-3:4*10^-3;
%create 3d grid of points
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
%3d grid of potentials
V_exact=Potential(X,Y,Z);
%Potential that we want to find the location of in V_exact 
V_p=Potential(0.001,-0.0008,0.0035);
%code to find location, first find the linear indice of V_p in V_exact
linear=find(V_exact==V_p)
%Change linear indice into a coordinate
[i,j,k]=ind2sub(size(V_exact),linear);
```

The problem here is that `[i,j,k]` takes on multiple values, whereas I just want it to give me the indices of the element in `V_exact` which is equal to the return of `Potential(Potential(0.001,-0.0008,0.0035)`. Another problem is that, even if there are many such elements with that value, if I run `V_exact(i,j,k)`, I dont end up with all the points being equal to `V_p`, only some are. Can anyone understand what I am doing wrong, or what the code is outputting?

The `Potential` functions code:

```
function [outputArg1] = Potential(x,y,z)
k=8987551788.7;
q1=1;
q2=-1;
outputArg1 = (k*q1)./sqrt(x.^2+(y-1*10^-3).^2+z.^2) + (k*q2)./sqrt(x.^2+(y+1*10^-3).^2+z.^2);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function Potential is non-injective, different input can give you the same output. This is why you have multiple value in your linear index `linear`.

It's hard to visualize the result of your function since we would need a 4D plot. But we can fixe one coordinate to visualize only one "layer" in 3D. For example we choose that `z = z(50)`.

```
surf(X(:,:,50),Y(:,:,50),V_exact(:,:,50),'EdgeColor','none')
hold on
contour3(X(:,:,50),Y(:,:,50),V_exact(:,:,50),'red')
```

[image]

All the isoline (in red) have the same, non unique, `V_exact` value.

Now to access `V_exact` you need to use the **linear** index, read the doc about array indexing! So all the value of `V_exact(linear)` will be equal to `V_p`.